# Title Screen Not Running Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create a title screen for a game I'm making, but when I run the program it's just a black canvas. Without the title, everything works fine and the game (which is a maze) runs perfectly, but if I try to add my title fcn everything messes up.
When running my program I'm calling:

```
game_intro()
game_loop() #the fcn that stores my game code
```

This is my title fcn code:

```
def game_intro():
    intro = True
    while intro == True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

    screen.fill((WHITE))
    largeText = pygame.font.Font(None, 115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("H&D: Hedges and Dragons", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((DISPLAY_WIDTH/2), (DISPLAY_HEIGHT/2))
    screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

I appreciate any help or advice!

Comment: Your `game_intro` function will stall in the initial `while` loop checking for a quit event. the code below will never run -- it should be indented to the same level as the `for` loop so that it may run after events have been processed. Then you need some way to exit your `while` loop, perhaps setting `intro` to False on a keypress or other event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize pygame right before the while loop:

```
def game_intro():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 900))
    intro = True
    while intro: #do not need intro == True
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               pygame.quit()
               quit()

    screen.fill((WHITE))
    largeText = pygame.font.Font(None, 115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("H&D: Hedges and Dragons", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((DISPLAY_WIDTH/2), (DISPLAY_HEIGHT/2))
    screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```